# What is a TRAMPOLINE_ADDR for ARM and ARM64(aarch64)?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cpu-architecture

I am writing a basic check-pointing mechanism for ARM64 using PTrace in order to do so I am using some code from cryopid and I found a TRAMPOLINE_ADDR macro like the following:

```
#define TRAMPOLINE_ADDR     0x00800000   /* 8MB mark */ for x86
#define TRAMPOLINE_ADDR     0x00300000   /* 3MB mark */ for x86_64
```

So when I read about trampolines it is something related to jump statements. But my questions is from where the above values came and what would the corresponding values for the ARM and ARM64 platform.

Thank you

Comment: "Trampoline": several meanings, generically "how do you 'bounce' from A to B".  @dwelch says just read wikipedia, but that doesn't help figure out what flavor of trampoline is going on. I don't know for sure - if I did, I would answer, not comment - but in system programming "trampoline" often relates to UNIX signal handling.  In bad old days kernel wrote code(!) onto user stack to branch to the signal handler & return when done. Ptrace similar. So I would grep for signal and ptrace in your ARM OS. (Guess: those code addresses are std trampolines, avoiding need to write code on stack.)

Answer (score 0):

Just read the wikipedia page.

There is nothing magic about a trampoline or certainly a particular address, any address where you can have code that executes can hold a trampoline.  there are many use cases for them...for example

say you are booting off of a flash, a spi flash, running at some safe rate so that the chip boots for all users.  But you want to increase the rate of the spi flash and the spi peripheral does not allow you to change while executing code.  So you would copy some code to ram, that code boosts the spi flash rate to a faster rate so you can use and/or run the flash faster, then you bounce back to running from the flash.  you have bounced or trampolined off of that little bit of code in ram.

you have a chip that boots from flash, but has the ability to re-map that address space to ram for example, so you copy some code to some other ram, branch to it that little bit of trampoline code remaps the address space, then bounces you back or bounces you to where the flash is now mapped to or whatever.

you will see the gnu linker sometimes add a small trampoline, say you compile some modules as thumb and some others for arm, you no longer have to use that interwork thing, the linker takes care of cleaning this up, it may add an instruction or two to trampoline you between modes, sometimes it modifies the code to just go where it needs to sometimes it modifies the code to branch link somewhere close and that somewhere close is a trampoline.

I assume there may be a need to do the same thing for aarch64 if/when switching to that mode.

so there should be no magic.  your specific application might have one or many trampolines, and the one you are interested might not even be called that, but is probably application specific, absolutely no reason why there would be one address for everyone, unless it is some very rigid operating specific (again "application specific") thing and one specific trampoline for that operating system is at some DEFINEd address.